# Keep a python script running on google VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I set up a VM with google and want it to run a python script persistently. If I exit out of the SSH session, the script stops. Is there a simple way to keep this thing going after I log out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can open an SSH session you install any number of terminal multiplexers such as tmux, screen or byobu.

If you can't install things on your VM, invoking the script every minute via a cron job could also solve the issue.

Comment: Cool. I installed screen, launched with `screen` ran my python script, exited out of my ssh and it looks like the job is still running. Just what I needed. If I log back in, how would I stop screen?

Comment: Disregard - I self resolved this one. It's done with `screen -r`